# Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '(click)' is not a valid attribute name

Tags: jquery, angular

I am using angular2 typescript.

inside ngOnInit I initialize a jstree pluging.

```
jQuery('#data').jstree({
    'core': {
        "check_callback": true,
        "themes": { "stripes": true },

        'data':  d

    }
})
```

this plugin is building  menu tree(li a) dynamically using json string.

the plugin can set attribute to anchor  using the  json like this

```
 object= {
                text: dataObject.partner_company_name,
                icon: "",
                state: {
                    'opened': true,
                    selected: false
                },
                 id: dataObject.partner_company_name,
                children: [],
                a_attr:{"(click)":"redirectToComponent","userid":userid,'level':'2'}
            }
```

when a user click on the anchor he sould navigte to other component base on userid and the level.

obviously I can't set angular2 click dynamically, so how can I accomplish the task and navigate the user to the right component base on the other attribute?

this is my component

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import {CookieService} from 'angular2-cookie/core';
    import {ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';
    import { Observable }       from 'rxjs/Observable';
    import { MainService } from './main.service';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    declare var jQuery:any;


    @Component({
      selector: 'ff-ff',
         templateUrl:'app/main/master.component.html',
           encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
             styleUrls: ['app/css/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css','app/main/master.component.css']
    })
    export class MasterComponent {
         constructor(private _cookieService:CookieService,private LogService:MainService,protected router: Router){}

         ngOnInit(): void {


    jQuery('#data').jstree({
        'core': {
            "check_callback": true,
            "themes": { "stripes": true },
            'data':  [
           {
                    text: 111,
                    icon: "",
                    state: {
                        'opened': true,
                        selected: false
                    },
                     id: dataObject.partner_company_name,
                    children: [],
                    a_attr:{"(click)":"redirectToComponent","userid":userid,'level':'2'}
                },
{
                    text: dataObject.partner_company_name,
                    icon: "",
                    state: {
                        'opened': true,
                        selected: false
                    },
                     id: 222,
                    children: [],
                    a_attr:{"(click)":"redirectToComponent","userid":userid,'level':'2'}
                }
                    ]
        }
    })
    }
```

the result is menu added to the doom dynamically

```
<div id="data"><li><a userid="3"  level=2></a>
<li><a userid="4"  level=2></a></div>
```

I need to attach angular2 event listener to the anchor for navigating the user to the right component base on the click.

Comment: your doing angular stick with angular man :( angular2 is typescript which is compiled to javascript so the click attribute will be compiled and will look differently

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$("#someId").attr('onClick', 'alert("msg")')`? And why not `$(document).on('click', '#someId', function(){})`?

Comment: don't think it is possible to do it this way

Comment: I need to route to other component from this event.

Answer (score 3):

There is no Angular2 click event. `(click)` is just Angular2 syntax to add event handlers to the DOM `click` event.

Angular2 value and event bindings can't be added dynamically. They only work if they are added to a components template statically.

Just use

```
$("someId").attr("click","event")
```

Comment: the event need to use router.navigate to another component.can I do it from regular js event?

Comment: The scope of the information you provided in your question is so narrow that I don't know how to provide support. Please edit your question and add the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish.

Comment: I update the question, hope the task will be more clear now

Comment: I don't know jstree and to me it's still entirely unclear what you try to accomplish.

Comment: the jstree is building li a menu dynamically .the plugin allow to add attribute to the dom using jquery attr.I need to attach angular2 click event to this menu or add event listener to the component

Comment: Without a component you can't do anything of this. What does your component look like?